# Simple INSERT doesnt work?

Tags: php, sql, insert

This simple code won't work and I really dont't know why

Any help will be appreciated

```
   <body>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {


        $sql = "INSERT INTO am (schulwoche,kalenderwoche,lehrstoff,anmerkungen,lehrer) VALUES ('".$_GET["sw"]."','".$_GET["kw"]."','".$_GET["ls"]."','".$_GET["an"]."','".$_GET["le"]."')";
        $conn->query($sql1);
    }
    ?>
    <div class="anzeige">
        <form action="insert.php" method="post">
            <b>Schulwoche: </b><input type="text" name="sw"><br>
            <b>Kalenderwoche: </b><input type="text" name="kw"><br>
            <b>Lehrstoff: </b><input type="text" name="ls"><br>
            <b>Anmkerkungen: </b><input type="text" name="an"><br>
            <b>Lehrer: </b><input type="text" name="le"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Eintragen">
        </form>
```

Comment: change $_GET to $_POST in your query string.

Comment: "won't work"? causes the server to catch file?

Comment: BTW I have changed the "insert.php" to "index.php" but that did not work either

Comment: open to SQL injection attack, dont use this code in production.

Comment: Please read about [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: Aehm... you did see, that you wrote `$sql = ...` and then `$conn->query($sql1);` (note the `1` at the end of `$sql1`)?

Comment: so Ive changed sql1 to sql and still doesnt work, the site seems to work fine but it doesnt insert any data into the table. I guess the form and the php code arent connected to each other, so they are executed as two different codes thats why I get a blank result because the submit isnt connected to the insert code. but actually it is?

Comment: i really hope you read the first comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What is the error you receive? My bet is that one of the get variables are missing at run time and you are trying to insert a null into a required field.

Its also possible that there are other fields in your am table that you are not populating using your php/sql insert syntax.

Try this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO am (schulwoche,kalenderwoche,lehrstoff,anmerkungen,lehrer) VALUES ('".$_GET["sw"]."','".$_GET["kw"]."','".$_GET["ls"]."','".$_GET["an"]."','".$_GET["le"]."')";
echo $sql;
```

Then copy the SQL and try run it directly on your database via the terminal or something. You will quickly see what is wrong.

Comment: the insert code works when I execute it in phpmyadmin. But it does not in the .php file

Comment: you mean the .php file? theres no error the site just gets blank. The submit button probably isn't linked to the INSERT query but I dont know what else to try

Comment: Do you have access to php.ini or any server config to turn error reporting on?